# i want to diplay a custom term value but it gives fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display my custom terms from tags, even the code is valid in front of me but it gives the fatal error i use this code

```
<p style="width:50%;float:left;">
<?php $dataTax = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ', '');
$dataMeta = get_post_meta($postID, 'genre', true);
if ((!empty($dataTax)) || (!empty($dataMeta))){ ?>
   <span class="data-info">Genre:<span itemprop="genre"></span></span>
   <?php if ($dataTax != ""){
      // strip links until we're ready to use the taxonomy pages in the future
      echo strip_tags($dataTax);
   } else {
   echo $dataMeta;
   }
 } ?>
</p>
```

"genre" is my taxonmy ,i want to dispaly their values,but it give me this type of error

```
Genre:
```

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in

Any help plz

Comment: It seems that your dataTax get's a WP_Error returned from `get_the_term_list()` What does `var_dump(dataTax)` show?

Comment: it would be very nice if you complete the error post being outputted..

Comment: it shows  " Genre: string(7) "dataTax"  "

Comment: or tell me any other method that we get the value from this term...

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: echo strip_tags($dataTax);  << here is the error occurs

Comment: Why don't you just remove `strip_tags`? Than see what happen ?
I think problem is in `strip_tags`, that gives fatal...

Comment: OMG i slove my problem, i import databe from other site then want to diplay this term value,but i cannot create this taxonomy on my new website,so now i just create taxanomy of same name then it pulls old values from database,so simple...hope so it help others as well

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the problem - something to do with deleting custom taxonomies when there are links in the Nav Menu which link to/are related to those now-missing taxonomies.

I read a post somewhere describing the exact problem, and this guy had spent a considerable amount of time trying to fix the problem without success. In the end he had fixed it by resetting WP back to a clean state (I assume a default database), which will of course result in complete loss of site data.

I would imagine there's a fix by delving into the database, but I've not explored this as the error I had was none-critical (on a localhost test site).

I keep on getting this problem, or related problems. Basically it happens whenever I rename a custom taxonomy or custom posts. I'm using the Custom Post Type UI plugin, and I created a load of custom posts & taxonomies. I then decided to change the name of some of the taxonomies from sentence case to lowercase, and this is where it screwed various plugins (e.g. Query Multiple Taxonomies) and the wp-menu (Appearance / menu). When I changed the name of some of the taxonomies back, everything started working ok again (although had to delete the query multiple taxonomies widget, and add it back in again).

Bottom line seems to be, once you've created your custom posts/taxonomies, don't alter them.

Deleted a menu that you had created in another theme would somehow fix it if you done this.

Kinda lame solution, but works as a charm.

*Some solutions from wordpress forums.*

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp_error-could-not-be-converted-to-string-11

Comment: OMG i slove my problem, i import databe from other site then want to diplay this term value,but i cannot create this taxonomy on my new website,so now i just create taxanomy of same name then it pulls old values from database,so simple...hope so it help others as well

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
echo strip_tags($dataTax);
```

with

```
print_r($dataTax);
```

and if you get something like: "WP_Error Object ( [errors]......"
check is "genre" a right name of $taxonomy